# JavaFX Gridpane search returns null nodes

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I want to implement my own custom dialogs in `JavaFX` from FXML files and I want to change the title and messages of the dialogs programmatically. My `.fxml` file has this structure for a typical dialog (I used an error one for this example):

```
<StackPane prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="290.0" style="-fx-background-color: #333333;" stylesheets="/style.css"
           xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
           fx:controller="apps.utils.Dialogs">
    <children>
        <BorderPane>
            <center>
                <GridPane>
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Error msg" textFill="LIGHTGRAY"/>
                        <Text fill="LIGHTGRAY" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0"
                              text="My custom error message here"
                              wrappingWidth="250.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                            <GridPane.margin>
                                <Insets top="10.0"/>
                            </GridPane.margin>
                        </Text>
                        <JFXButton onMouseClicked="#close"
                                   style="-fx-background-color: #da294f; -fx-border-radius: 5; -fx-background-radius: 5;"
                                   text="Retry" textFill="LIGHTGRAY" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
                                   GridPane.valignment="BASELINE">
                            <GridPane.margin>
                                <Insets top="20.0"/>
                            </GridPane.margin>
                        </JFXButton>
                    </children>
                </GridPane>
            </center>
            <StackPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
            </StackPane.margin>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

The method I use to show the dialog (in my controller class):

```
    public static void showDialog(StackPane rootPane, BorderPane rootBorderPane, URL dialogFile, String title, String message) throws IOException {
  rootBorderPane.setEffect(boxBlur);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(dialogFile);
        loader.setClassLoader(cachingClassLoader);
        StackPane dialog = loader.load();
        ObservableList<Node> components = dialog.getChildren();
        BorderPane pane = (BorderPane) components.get(0);
        GridPane content = (GridPane) pane.getCenter();
        System.out.println("row: " + content.getRowCount() + " col:" + content.getColumnCount()); //prints Row 3, col 1

        Label dialogTitle = (Label) findNodeFromIndex(content, 0, 0);
        dialogTitle.setText(title);
        Text dialogMessage = (Text) findNodeFromIndex(content, 0, 1);
        dialogMessage.setText(message);
        //rest of the code to show dialog...
}
```

Then I have a function to search through the Gridpane like this:

```
   private static Node findNodeFromIndex(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridPane.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            Node node = gridPane.getChildren().get(i);
            if (GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row && GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col) {
                return node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then I simply call `showDialog()` with the dialog type, and heading as well as custom heading/body text as my parameters.

Now my issue is, I get a `NullPointerException` on the `setText()` methods. I can't figure out why that is. How could I fix this?

Comment: Since you don't set the row index on some elements, those won't match when you search for them at zero, so your `findNodeFromIndex` returns null. This is just a really ugly way to do this anyway; why not get a reference to the controller, and define methods in the controller to set the title and message? Then you avoid searching through the scene graph like this completely (note how badly your code will break if you make any slight modification to the layout).

Comment: Oh that might be it. I didn't check the fxml files for that. I only checked in Scenebuilder and they show the `rowIndex`. Getting a reference to the controller was the first thing I tried. Using `@FXML` but it always returned a null value. I guess I have to hardcode it in myself, but that's something I wanted to avoid. I figured well since i'm sure I'll always have the title and message as first and second row, then I could do it that way. I also didn't want to spend much time on it but In hindsight, the time i've spent on this other method probably makes no difference now.

Comment: ??? Just call `loader.getController()` after you call `load()`

Comment: I believe that's what I did. I think the titles of my controls were a little off though. I know you have to concatenate `Controller` after the name of the `fxml` file. But how would you handle the `_`character? For instance if the id of the file is `my_dialog.fxml`. Should the controller be `my_dialogController` or `myDialogController`?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you are talking about in that last comment. There are no `<fx:include>` tags visible in the code you posted.

Comment: Oh, In my first attempt I had one fxml file with an `<fx:include>` in a pane. to populate the different dialog layouts. I'd then change the layouts based on whatever dialog I wanted. I just realised now that you can use the same fx:ids on different files on the same controller so I didn't even need two files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `findNodeFromIndex()` is returning `null` because you don't explicitly set the column index on the nodes in column 0, etc.

Searching through the scene graph manually like this is just not the right way to approach this at all. Any small change to the layout will completely break this code. Instead, just define methods in the controller class to set the title and message:

```
public class Dialogs {

    @FXML
    private Label titleLabel ;

    @FXML
    private Text messageText ;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        titleLabel.setText(title);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        messageText.setText(message);
    }

    // ...
}
```

and set the `fx:id`s on your elements in the FXML:

```xml
<Label fx:id="titleLabel" text="Error msg" textFill="LIGHTGRAY"/>
<Text fx:id="messageText" fill="LIGHTGRAY" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0"
      text="My custom error message here"
      wrappingWidth="250.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
```

Then you can just call those methods:

```
public static void showDialog(StackPane rootPane, BorderPane rootBorderPane, URL dialogFile, String title, String message) throws IOException {
    rootBorderPane.setEffect(boxBlur);

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(dialogFile);
    loader.setClassLoader(cachingClassLoader);
    StackPane dialog = loader.load();
    Dialogs controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setTitle(title);
    controller.setMessage(message);
    //rest of the code to show dialog...

}
```

Comment: thank you. Good stuff. I was missing the `loader.getController` line